# I'm using Sinatra and my assets (sass) are not working on heroku

Tags: heroku, sass, sinatra

My assets are working perfectly in development on my local machine. However, when I deploy to Heroku the styles are not working.I have the following directory structure. What do I need to do in order to get my assets working on Heroku?

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── codekit-config.json
├── config.ru
├── development.db
├── main.rb
├── public
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── styles.css
│   │   │   └── styles.scss
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   │   └── sinatra.jpg
│   │   ├── js
│   │   └── sass
│   └── favicon.ico
├── song.rb
└── views
    ├── about.haml
    ├── contact.haml
    ├── edit_song.haml
    ├── home.haml
    ├── layout.haml
    ├── login.haml
    ├── nav.haml
    ├── new_song.haml
    ├── not_found.haml
    ├── show_song.haml
    ├── song_form.haml
    └── songs.haml
```

7 directories, 24 files

## main.app

```
require 'sinatra/flash'
require 'sinatra'
require './song'
require 'sass'
require 'haml'
require 'sinatra/assetpack'

register Sinatra::AssetPack
# I dont' think I need the line below if I use codekit
# get('assets/css/styles.css') { scss :styles}

configure :development do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite3://#{Dir.pwd}/development.db")
end

configure :production do
  DataMapper.setup(:default, ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
end

assets do

  js :application, [
    '/js/jquery.js',
    '/js/app.js'
    # You can also do this: 'js/*.js'
  ]

  css :application, [
    '/assets/css/styles.css',
    '/assets/css/styles.scss',
   ]

  js_compression :jsmin
  css_compression :sass

end
configure do
  enable :sessions
  set :username, 'frank'
  set :password, 'sinatra'
end

helpers do
  def set_title
    @title ||= "Songs By Russell"
  end


end

before do
  set_title
end

get '/login' do
  haml :login
end

post '/login' do
  if params[:username] == settings.username && params[:password] == settings.password
    session[:admin] = true
    redirect to('/songs')
  else
    haml :login
  end
end

get '/logout' do
  session.clear
  redirect to('/login')
end

get '/set/:name' do
  session[:name] = params[:name]
end

get '/' do
  haml :home
end

get '/about' do
  @title = "All About This Website"
  haml :about
end

get '/contact' do
  haml :contact
end

post '/contact' do
  send_message
  flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your message. We'll be in touch soon."
end

not_found do
  haml :not_found
end
```

## config.ru

```
require './main'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't write to the filesystem with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). Either precompile the assets (via [sinatra-assetpack](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack#precompile) or otherwise) and check them in and then push, or use your own [sass route](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Sass%20Templates).

Comment: But I hear if you have `rake assets:precompile` task it gets run on push. For CoffeeScript I am getting an error.

Comment: This is the error I get, https://gist.github.com/ziyan-junaideen/82a17b49d0cc5be27b1c

Comment: That is a Sinatra app btw. Wonder how to get over it.

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen use Sprockets https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack/issues/62#issuecomment-35810507

Comment: I am using RequireJS for JavaScripts and couldn't figure out how to get it done with some thing like asset pack. Thus my interest to custom compile. Any ways I opened and issue in SO about my interest. If some thing shows up I will add a link here.